# Continuity on [0,2) of the modulus of convexity

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

For a Banach space $X$ the mapping
$$\delta_X\colon[0,2]\to[0,1], \varepsilon\mapsto \inf\{1-|x+y|/2\colon |x|\leq 1, |y|\leq 1, \text{and } |x-y|\geq\varepsilon\} $$
is called the modulus of convexity of $X$. I read at multiple places that $\delta_X$ is continuous on $[0,2)$ but I could not find a proof.

So my question is: how to prove that the modulus of convexity is continuous on $[0,2)$?

Of course, when $\delta_X$ is convex it is easy to see that it is continuous on $(0,2)$ but unfortunately this is not the case in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the original proof of this result is due to V. I. Gurariĭ and published in the Russian paper "V. I. Gurariĭ: Differential properties of the convexity moduli of Banach spaces, Mat. Issled. 2 (1967), no. 1, 141–148".

Unfortunately it seems that this paper is hard to obtain.

The result is also a special case of the results on the modulus of $k$-convexity presented in [Lim, Teck-Cheong: On moduli of k-convexity. Abstr. Appl. Anal. 4 (1999), no. 4, 243–247](http://www.hindawi.com/journals/aaa/1999/752421/abs/)