# Modulus of convexity - continuous function

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis

I need to prove that modulus of convexity of a Banach space is a continuous function. Where can I find this proof?

Modulus of convexity we define in the following way:

$$
\delta(\varepsilon)=\inf\{1 -\frac{\|x+y\|}{2}:x,y\in B_{1},\|x-y\|\geq \varepsilon \}.
$$

Comment: Maybe https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1772875/27978

Comment: @copper.hat Yes, I saw this but they say that paper with the original proof is hard to obtain and I can't find it

Answer (score 1):

It is not continuous! Example: The space $X=C[0,1]$ equipped with the norm $|||x|||=||x||_C+||x||_L$  is strictly convex, which implies $\delta(2)=1$. On the other hand, $\delta(\varepsilon)=0$ for $0\le\varepsilon<2$.